# Two GPU's Freeze Issue Nvidia/AMD

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have two GPU's installed in my system, I want to use a GT 710 for the Ubuntu host OS and an R9 390 to passthrough a Windows VM. I blacklisted the R9 390 and I have no driver installed for that card. When booting up with the GT 710 on the latest kernel the system starts freezing right after I login and eventually will stop responding. I tried booting on the R9 390 and switching from the open source drivers to Nvidia's but after reboot this caused the GT 710 to not output anything at all. But on the latest kernel and with the Nvidia drivers installed if I completely remove my R9 390 from my system Ubuntu boots perfectly fine and it is completely stable. I do not understand at all what's wrong, I feel like there shouldn't be any kind of graphic driver issues since I did not install any drivers for my R9 390, just for my GT 710.

Answer (score 0):

Found out this wasn't due to any software issues and that it was because I was trying to passthrough the primary GPU in my system causing Ubuntu to freak out.